# mixed predicator types for Random forest

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to build a classification model using Random forest for a data set with 5 predicator variables. two predicator variable are of continuous type, one can be a real value in the interval of `[0, 1000]` while the other one can be a real value of `[-10, 10]`; one predicator variable is of integer values of `[10000, 15000]`. In addition, the two remaining predicator variables are of categorical values, i.e., `{ A, B, C, D, E F}` and `{NY, LA, Chicago}`. Are there any procedures required for pre-processing these different predicator types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many of the exhaustive search algorithms will be biased towards variables with many values. separating the variable selection and split selection process seems to help this, as described in [this](http://statmath.wu-wien.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/Hothorn+Hornik+Zeileis-2006.pdf) paper. they have a [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) implemented in R as well. i don't know of a way to avoid this with mixed type data using the more common approaches. however, despite the fact that this problem results in bias, in my experience the predictive performance hasn't been hugely different, so your mileage may vary. it depends on what you are doing. i'd do some simulations either way. the same group has two bmc bioinformatics papers on conditional permutation importance that discuss these issues.